# Unable to delete a determinate position in the struct, the data persist

Tags: c, function, struct, position

First at all english its not my first language i will try my best.

Hello guys, I have a problem i'm trying to delete a determinate position of the struct, so instead of deleting the info inside by modifying the string with strcpy or just setting the int or float to 0 i want to erase the data in the struct by changing the position with the next one so 1.2.3.4.5 will be 1.2<-3.4.5 and stay this way 1.2.3.4, problem is after 1h trying to make it works there are some problems, first: if there's only one student after the program ask me for the id to erase, the new id seems to be a random number or like garbage data, so i guess the position changed but the data inside of this id persist.

Example:

id: 1
name: john
lastname: smith
score1: 2
score2: 5
score3: 6

After the function ask me for the id to be erased:

id: 425262
name: john
lastname: smith
score1: 2
score2: 5
score3: 6

the second issue is, if i insert some students, and the program ask  for the id to be erased, all id numbers changes to that id i just insert instead of deleting the id target.

**Heres the full code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alumnos{
   int      id;
   char     alumno[10];
   char     apellido[15];
   float    nota1;
   float    nota2;
   float    nota3;
};


int  insertar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20],int n,int *id_alumno);
void mostrar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20],int n);
void buscar_alumno(struct alumnos notas[20],int n);
void cambiar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20],int n);
void eliminar_alumno(struct alumnos notas[20],int n);


int main (void){

    int menu = 0, n = 0, id_alumno = 1;
    struct alumnos notas[20];


    puts("\n<><><>Bienvenido al recuento de notas de la escuela<><><>\n"); 
    puts("\nQue deseas hacer?\n"); 


    while (menu != 6){

        puts("\n1)Insertas las notas de un alumno\n2)Ver todas las notas\n3)Ver las notas de un alumno\n4)Modificar notas\n5)Eliminar datos del alumno\n6)Salir\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        switch(menu){

            case 1:

                n=insertar_notas(notas,n,&id_alumno);
                break;

            case 2:

                mostrar_notas(notas,n);
                break;

            case 3:

                buscar_alumno(notas,n);
                break;

            case 4:

                cambiar_notas(notas,n);
                break;

            case 5:

                eliminar_alumno(notas,n);
                break;
        }
    }
}


int insertar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20], int n,int *id_alumno){

    char resp[3];

    system("cls");
    puts("\n \a Insercion del alumno\n"); 
    while (!strstr(resp,"no")){
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEl ID de este alumno sera: %d\n", *id_alumno);
        notas[n].id=*id_alumno;
        (*id_alumno)++;
        puts("\nDime el nombre del Alumno\n");
        scanf("%10s", notas[n].alumno );
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        puts("\nDime el apellido del Alumno\n");
        scanf("%10s", notas[n].apellido );
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime la Primera nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
        scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota1 );
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime la Segunda nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
        scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota2 );
        system("cls");
        puts("\nDime la Tercera nota trimestral del Alumno[1.23]\n");
        scanf("%f", &notas[n].nota3 );
        n++;
        system("cls");
        puts("\nQuieres volver a insertar otro?[si|no]\n");
        scanf("%3s", resp);
        strlwr(resp);

    }

    return n;
}

void mostrar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20],int n){

    int i;

    system("cls");

    if (n != 0 ){

        puts("\nLos alumnos insertados son:\n"); 

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("\n\nID %d\n\n Nombre:%s\n Apellido: %s\n Primera nota:%0.2f\n Segunda nota:%0.2f\n Tercera nota:%0.2f\n\n", notas[i].id, notas[i].alumno, notas[i].apellido ,notas[i].nota1 ,notas[i].nota2 ,notas[i].nota3 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts("\n \aNo hay registro\n");
    }
}

void buscar_alumno(struct alumnos notas[20],int n){

    int num = 0;
    float media;

    if (n != 0){

        char ape_alumno[15];

        system("cls");
        puts("\n\aBusqueda por alumno\n");

        puts("\nDime el apellido del alumno\n");
        scanf("%15s", ape_alumno);

        for ( num = 0; num < n ; num++){

            if (strcmp(notas[num].apellido,ape_alumno)==0){

                printf("\nEl alumno introducido es: %s %s\n", notas[num].alumno, notas[num].apellido );

                media=(notas[num].nota1+notas[num].nota2+notas[num].nota3)/3;

                printf("\nLa nota media es %0.2f \n", media);

                if (media<5){

                    puts("\nSuspendido no hace media\n");
                }

                if (media=5 & media>6){

                    puts("\nSuficiente\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }else{

        puts("\a\nRegistro vacio\n");
    }
}

void cambiar_notas(struct alumnos notas[20],int n){

    char ape_notas[15];
    float nueva_nota1,nueva_nota2,nueva_nota3,nota_n1t,nota_n2t,nota_n3t;

    int j = 0, submenu_mod = 0, nota_mod;

    if (n != 0){

        system("cls");
        puts("\n \aDime el apellido del alumno a modificar las notas\n");
        scanf("%15s", ape_notas);

        for (j = 0;j < n; j++){

            if (strcmp(notas[j].apellido,ape_notas)==0){

                printf("\nLas notas de este alumno %s %s son:\n \n1r Trimestre:%0.2f\n \n2n Trimestre:%0.2f\n \n3r Trimestre:%0.2f\n", notas[j].alumno,notas[j].apellido,notas[j].nota1 ,notas[j].nota2 ,notas[j].nota3 );

                while(submenu_mod != 3){
                    puts("\nQue quieres hacer?:\n\n1)Modificar todas las notas\n2)Modificar solo una nota\n3)Salir\n");
                    scanf("%d", &submenu_mod);
                    switch(submenu_mod){

                        case 1:
                            puts("\nDime la primera nota trimestral\n");
                            scanf("%f", &nueva_nota1);
                            puts("\nDime la segunda nota trimestral\n");
                            scanf("%f", &nueva_nota2);
                            puts("\nDime la tercera nota trimestral\n");
                            scanf("%f", &nueva_nota3);

                            notas[j].nota1=nueva_nota1;
                            notas[j].nota2=nueva_nota2;
                            notas[j].nota3=nueva_nota3;

                            printf("\nLas nuevas notas de este alumno son:\n \n1r Trimestre:%0.2f\n \n2n Trimestre:%0.2f\n \n3r Trimestre:%0.2f\n", notas[j].nota1 ,notas[j].nota2 ,notas[j].nota3 );
                            system("pause");
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            while (nota_mod != 4){
                                puts("\nQue nota trimestral quieres modificar?:\n");
                                printf("\n1)Nota trimestral %0.2f\n2)Nota trimestral %0.2f\n3)Nota trimestral %0.2f\n4)Salir", notas[j].nota1,notas[j].nota2,notas[j].nota3);
                                scanf("%d", &nota_mod);
                                switch(nota_mod){

                                    case 1:
                                        puts("\nDime la nueva nota del Primer trimestre:\n");
                                        scanf("%f", &nota_n1t);
                                        notas[j].nota1=nota_n1t;
                                        printf("La nueva nota del primer trimestre para el alumno %s %s es: \n%0.2f", notas[j].alumno,notas[j].apellido,notas[j].nota1);
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                        puts("\nDime la nueva nota del Segundo trimestre:\n");
                                        scanf("%f", &nota_n2t);
                                        notas[j].nota2=nota_n2t;
                                        printf("La nueva nota del Segundo trimestre para el alumno %s %s es: \n%0.2f", notas[j].alumno,notas[j].apellido,notas[j].nota2);
                                        break;

                                    case 3:

                                        puts("\nDime la nueva nota del Tercer trimestre:\n");
                                        scanf("%f", &nota_n3t);
                                        notas[j].nota3=nota_n3t;
                                        printf("La nueva nota del Tercer trimestre para el alumno %s %s es: \n%0.2f", notas[j].alumno,notas[j].apellido,notas[j].nota3);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            } else {

                puts("\nNo se ha encontrado ese apellido\n");
            }
        }
    } else {

        system("cls");
        puts("\n \aRegistro vacio\n");
    }
}
```

**The function:**

```
void eliminar_alumno(struct alumnos notas[20],int n){

    int id_eli = 0, r = 0;

    mostrar_notas(notas,n);

    puts("\nInserta la id del alumno a eliminar\n");
    scanf("%d",&id_eli);

    for(r = 0;r < n;r++){

        if (notas[r].id = id_eli){
            notas[r].id=notas[r+1].id;
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really too long code!! hard to look.

Comment: `if (media=5 & media>6)` should be `if (media==5 && media>6)` in function `buscar_alumno(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with warnings:

```
if (notas[r].id = id_eli){
```

should be

```
if (notas[r].id == id_eli){
```

Also, this is wrong:

```
     if (media=5 & media>6){
```

Suficiente = `[5 - 6)` right? Then you want `if (media >= 5 && media < 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes in your `eliminar_alumno` function-

```
for(r = 0;r < n;r++){
       if (notas[r].id == id_eli){
       for(i=r;i < (n-1);i++)
            notas[i]=notas[i+1];
       notas[i].id -= 1;
       n--;
       }
}
```

Comment: Same as before, now id dosent seems to be affected.